# Error for PDF "InvalidPDFException: Invalid PDF structure" for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, plugins

I have problem error for pdf, when open a pdf, error notification pops up: "InvalidPDFException: Invalid PDF structure"
This for plugin real3dflipbook wordpress

How do I fix it? What need requirement server Cpanel? I mean what version php or max_input_var and anything....

Comment: ### wp-server ###
 
server_architecture: Linux 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 x86_64
httpd_software: Apache
php_version: 7.1.30 64 bit
php_sapi: cgi-fcgi
max_input_variables: 1000
time_limit: 300
memory_limit: 256M
max_input_time: 90
upload_max_size: 128M
php_post_max_size: 128M
curl_version: 7.29.0 NSS/3.36
suhosin: false
imagick_availability: true
htaccess_extra_rules: true

Comment: ### wp-database ###
 
extension: mysqli
server_version: 5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB
client_version: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 -

Comment: ### wp-constants ###
 
WP_HOME: undefined
WP_SITEURL: undefined
WP_CONTENT_DIR: 
WP_PLUGIN_DIR: 
WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT: 256M
WP_DEBUG: false
WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY: true
WP_DEBUG_LOG: false
SCRIPT_DEBUG: false
WP_CACHE: true
CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS: undefined
COMPRESS_SCRIPTS: undefined
COMPRESS_CSS: undefined
WP_LOCAL_DEV: undefined

Comment: Can you tell me where are showing this pdf file.If possible share the image of it.

Comment: Hey Jinesh, Notification error "InvalidPDFException: Invalid PDF structure" when click on pdf(real3d flipbook) come error and just loading... but not open till just loading

Comment: Is it possible to share url?

Comment: i fount fix it, this is IDM(Internet Download Manager), i disable browser and working...

Comment: okay that's good